# Disable global Ctrl-Alt-L hotkey in KDE

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

The IntelliJ IDEA short-cut to reformat source code is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.  This happens to lock the screen in KDE (Gnome too?).  How can I disable this so IntelliJ receives the key sequence?

Comment: for Gnome, this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/571389/332327) helps

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Under the K menu, go to the Control Center.

Regional & Accessibility |
Keyboard Shortcuts |
Shortcut Schemes tab,
Global Shortcuts tab.

In the search box, type "lock", which should narrow the visible shortcuts and show the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> one ("Lock Session").

Underneath, click None.

Click the Apply button.

---

On KDE Plasma 5 go to System Settings | Desktop Behaviour | Screen Locking

Here you will find a "Keyboard Shortcut" option. Change it to something else or set to none

Comment: Note: This answer is for KDE 3 only.

Comment: And for KDE 4. But you have to select "KDE Session" as "KDE Component".

Comment: KDE 4.3: System Settings -> Keyboard and Mouse -> Global Keyboard Shortcuts -> Run Command Interface -> Lock Session

Answer (score 13):

On Kubuntu 11.10 it's *well hidden*:

1. Start **System Settings**
2. Under **Common Appearance and Behavior**, select **Shortcuts and Gestures**.
3. Select **Global Keyboard Shortcuts** in the left-hand panel.
4. Select the KDE Component: **Run Command Interface** (important, otherwise you won't see the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> mapping!)
5. Select **Lock Session**
6. Edit the setting, either choose a different mapping or 'none'.

Comment: @German sorry to hear that.   KUbuntu 11.10 is pretty old by now. :)

Comment: For Kubuntu 13.10, instead of the **Run Command Interface**, select **The KDE Session Manager**. In there, you will find the **Lock Session** option.

Comment: In Kubuntu 15.04 they have moved it again. No it is in System Settings >> Shortcuts >> Global Keyboard Shortcuts >> ksmserver >> Lock Session

Answer (score 8):

I eventually found how to disable the lock screen key binding (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>) in the System Setting app.

System Settings->"Keyboard Mouse->Keyboard Shortcuts

I had to choose the KDE component: Run Command Interface.

I'm running KDE on Fedora Core 9.

Answer (score 6):

For Linux Mint:
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> System -> Lock screen

Comment: What a great idea to show you the key combination only once you've clicked on a command, isn't it? Because if you want to disable a certain one, you have to click on ALL commands until you find the right one. Good job, Mint.

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to disable all global keyboard shortcuts in KDE for specific applications. I've done it in KDE 4 and now I've done it in KDE 5 again. So in KDE 5 right click on your application's window title -> More actions -> Special Window Settings (or Special Application Settings) -> Appearance & Fixes -> Ignore Global Shortcuts -> Force, Yes. It's much easier than to look for each shortcut one by one.

You can check such configurations in System Settings -> Window Management -> Window Rules.

Comment: I usually replace alt with win (use the windows key instead of alt) so that I can use Intellij, but for some reason the global shortcuts comes back from time to time, so this solution is much better.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of disabling anything, you can also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> in most applications where this problem exists. KDE knows the meta key (aka the 'windows key'), but the applications seem to ignore it and consider it to be just <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd>.

Comment: Confirmed for Ubuntu 16.0.4, running in VirtualBox on Windows host.

Answer (score 2):

I know, old question, but I didn't easily find a decent answer. If anybody is wondering how to disable it on **Ubuntu** (while the <kbd>Windows_key</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut will still work):

Go to `Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts tab -> System -> select Lock screen and press backspace` to clear it.

Comment: Thanks. Was not able to find the key to disable it by my own.

Answer (score 1):

For **KDE Plasma 5**

1 - click on **K menu**, type keyboard, choose `Global Keyboard shortcuts`

2 - Choose the `KDE Session Manager` in **KDE component** , at `Lock Session`, do what you want, disable the shortcut or choose another!

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 16.04 `System settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut -> System -> LockScreen -> click-it and make changes`

I changed my to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> from <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>atl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Here is the Screen shot which tells where the above instructions will lead you to.
[Keyboard -> shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYz77.png)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change the Idea keymap to use Default for KDE. 
You can go to *File -> settings -> keymap* and then select the **Default for KDE** option from the drop down

Answer (score 0):

Also you can change it with the configuration file.

The following files store the keyboard shortcuts of KDE Plasma 5 and of some of its associated applications such as Konsole and KWrite.

```
~/.config/kdeglobals
~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc
~/.config/khotkeysrc
~/.config/kwinrc
~/.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/katepart/katepart5ui.rc
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/konsoleui.rc
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/sessionui.rc
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/kwrite/kwriteui.rc
```

Let me add descriptions for the files.

Standard Shortcuts (System Settings > Shortcuts)
~/.config/kdeglobals

Global Shortcuts (System Settings > Shortcuts)
~/.config/kglobalshortcutsrc

"Custom Shortcuts" (System Settings > Shortcuts)
~/.config/khotkeysrc

Konsole
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/konsoleui.rc
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/konsole/sessionui.rc

KWrite > Settings > Configure Shortcuts... > KWrite
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/kwrite/kwriteui.rc

KWrite > Settings > Configure Shortcuts... > Kate Part
~/.local/share/kxmlgui5/katepart/katepart5ui.rc

Answer (score 0):

For those who prefer visual answers, here's where this settings can be found
[image]

**IMPORTANT** Note that there are two values: *Global* and *Global Alternative*. I had to unbind the *Global Alternative* shortcut to resolve a problem with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 + KDE plasma:
Use Global Shorcuts -> System Setting Module menu -> Lock session. Set to "Custom -> None"
[image]